# How do I list all files in gcs bucket (with all folder) for a specific string match in the file content using gsutil command

Tags: unix, gsutil

I want to list the files in gcs bucket with multiple folders for a specific pattern of string within the file content. Is there any quick solution using gustil ?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter gcs path : " gcs_path
read -p "Enter pattern : " pattern
path=${gcs_path}**
#pattern=$2
echo "loading the list of files.."
gsutil ls -h $path > gcs_list.txt
echo "Looking for the pattern from the list...."
while read -r line ; do
##echo "Reading line :  $line"
if      gsutil cat $line | grep -q "$pattern"  ; then
        #true
        echo " Match found for $line"
fi
done < gcs_list.txt
echo "Pattern search done!!"
```

This will work. If someone have any better solution please update the same

Answer (score 0):

for i in `gsutil ls gs://path/to/folder/*.json`; do gsutil cat $i | jq -r .; done > file_mask_patterns.txt